# Printing conditional probabilities from Naive Bayes Model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, naivebayes

I have created a model using e1071 package for Naive Bayes classifier. I need to print the conditional probabilities in below format.

P(C=c1)=0.32 P(A1=x1|c1)=0.33 P(A1=x2|c1)=0.67 P(A2=y1|c1)=0.25 P(A2=y2|c1)=0.75
P(A3=z1|c1)=0.26 P(A3=z2|c1)=0.49 P(A3=z3|c1)=0.25

When I type model name, I can see the conditional probabilities but don't know how to access individual value and use it to print result in above format.

I am new to R and not sure how to parse model and get data in this form. How to parse model and separate out data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print $tables

```
> data(Titanic)
> m <- naiveBayes(Survived ~ ., data = Titanic)  
> m$tables
$Class
        Class
Survived        1st        2nd        3rd       Crew
     No  0.08187919 0.11208054 0.35436242 0.45167785
     Yes 0.28551336 0.16596343 0.25035162 0.29817159

$Sex
        Sex
Survived       Male     Female
     No  0.91543624 0.08456376
     Yes 0.51617440 0.48382560

$Age
        Age
Survived      Child      Adult
     No  0.03489933 0.96510067
     Yes 0.08016878 0.91983122
```

And now you can read out for example `P(Age=Child|Survived=No) = 3%` and `P(Age=Child|Survived=yes) = 8%`, `P(Class=Crew|Survived=No) = 45%` and so on.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, just want to make a small correction: `P(Age=Child|Survived)=Yes` should be 8% (directly from the conditional probability table shown in the answer).